# Error with editing a user [ASP MVC]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem with editing a user info , when I try to edit the nick name or email or phone number , and click save , nothing changed ....

here is my Account Controller Method :

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    // POST: /Account/Edit_Info

    public ActionResult Edit_Info(UserVm model)
    {
        var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var User_Model = db.AspNetUsers.Find(id);
            User_Model.NickName = model.User.NickName;
            User_Model.Email = model.User.Email;
            User_Model.PhoneNumber = model.User.PhoneNumber;
            db.Entry(User_Model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Here is my view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit_Info", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                                    {
                                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                        <h4>Personal Information</h4>
                                        <hr />
                                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.Id)

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.NickName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.NickName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.NickName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn green" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    }
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
 public class UserVm
{

    public List<Book> Books { set; get; }
    public AspNetUser User { set; get; }
    public List<ReadLater> ReadLaters { set; get; }
    public List<Favourite> Favourites { set; get; }
    public ChangePasswordViewModel ChangePasswordViewModel { set; get; }

}
```

can anyone help me with finding the problem and thanks

Comment: Is `ModelState` actually valid (and you hitting the code to save the data)? The last line of your controller method should be `return View(model);` (not `return RedirectToAction("Index");`) so that validation errors are displayed and can be corrected.

Comment: Actually you are right , it's solved @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve of this (Thanks @Stephen-Muecke) :

> Is ModelState actually valid (and you hitting the code to save the data)? The last line of your controller method should be return View(model); (not return RedirectToAction("Index");) so that validation errors are displayed and can be corrected.

```
public ActionResult Edit_Info(UserVm model)
{
    var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    if (id != null)
    {
        var User_Model = db.AspNetUsers.Find(id);
        User_Model.NickName = model.User.NickName;
        User_Model.Email = model.User.Email;
        User_Model.PhoneNumber = model.User.PhoneNumber;
        db.Entry(User_Model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return view (model);

}
```